# Nginx issue with two web nodes

Tags: nginx, cache

I'm running Wordpress website with Nginx and Memcached. I have simple DNS round robin balancing with A records pointing to both web servers. I've noticed the following entries in both web servers access logs:

```
192.168.1.10 example.com - [07/Jun/2012:22:43:58 +0100] "-" 400 0 "-" "-" - 0.000
192.168.1.10 example.com - [07/Jun/2012:22:43:58 +0100] "-" 400 0 "-" "-" - 0.000
192.168.1.10 example.com - [07/Jun/2012:22:43:58 +0100] "-" 400 0 "-" "-" - 0.000
192.168.1.10 example.com - [07/Jun/2012:22:43:58 +0100] "-" 400 0 "-" "-" - 0.000
192.168.1.10 example.com - [07/Jun/2012:22:43:58 +0100] "-" 400 0 "-" "-" - 0.000
```

I've configured W3 Total cache plugin for Wordpress - pointing to loopback address (127.0.0.1:11211) on each Wordpress installation.

Is this because the webserver is trying to access content that is cached on the other web server? Shall I add IPs to W3 plugin of both web servers on each website (192.168.1.:11211, 192.168.1.2:11211)?
I'm not sure if this related to Memcached or maybe some configuration issue on the server itself?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are "400 Bad Request", most likely just client connects without sending anything. Some load balancers / health checks known to cause a lots of these.

Also Google Chrome opens a lot of connections just in case, but may not use all of them.

Comment: Thanks. I think it was actually caused by Google Chrome.